# Will suspension pivots freeze in very cold conditions

Tags: full-suspension

[This question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/83515/14027) features what looks like a full suspension fat bike.
Whilst I don't think rear suspension is useful for a fat bike anyway, one thing occurred to me that I don't know the answer to.

Fat bikes are commonly used for snow riding in below freezing conditions.  Will these conditions cause the rear suspension pivots to freeze?

Comment: "Fat bikes are commonly used for snow riding in below freezing conditions." — yes but not necessarily. Fat tires are good for general offroad conditions, like traversing deep soft moss, even in summer. I ride my fat 4.8" wheels from the first snow until the last snow. Often it is already/still is positive (°C) temperatures. In the summer, I switch to narrower 3" tires. So, the same bike can be used year round, and it makes sense to have suspension on it for my usage.

Comment: But there is no doubt that full-suspension fat bikes are very niche thing. They are not used in any sort of serious racing, so no major manufacturer offers them. But this question still applies to "regular" dual suspension bicycles in cold conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rear pivots are just bearings or bushings. If they freeze, then other bushings and bearings on the bike will freeze simultaneously.

Some other places on a bike where there are bearings: wheel hubs, headset, bottom bracket. Places where there are bushings: rear derailleur parallelogram, chain links, suspension fork and dropper post. So, many of these parts are likely to be (un)affected together.

Oil and grease do not freeze but become stickier/coagulate which means higher friction in bearings, higher stiction in bushings and slower compression in suspension. So, every moving part on a bike becomes less efficient at very low temperatures.

Oil in hydraulic brakes gets stickier too. Even rubber in tires becomes stiffer and less grippy.

To counter that, there are oils/grease which work better at lower temperatures. E.g. one fat bike fork manufacturer recommends using thinner 3w oil for low temperatures instead of 5w oil.

I would say that if the temperature is so low that it becomes noticeable, the worsened performance of the rear suspension is not the primary problem. Here is my priority list of issues as the temperature falls down:

0. Frozen body parts. No sense in complaining about bike performance if the rider is not feeling their legs/fingers.
1. Weaker braking
2. Less tire grip
3. Affected front-end suspension

... <other things> ...

9. Sticky rear end

Needless to say, if you got water somewhere inside your parts, you'll feel negative effects of freezing much sooner, and they will be much worse. Seized brakes/shifting/freehubs are common issues.

Comment: TBH, nobody wants a "sticky rear end".

Comment: @FreeMan Really? On rainy days there seem to be a lot of cyclists with big brown stains on the garments on their rear ends. "Look at your pants, such a big boy" and all that :-)

Comment: Agree with Rechistov's answer. By the time a suspension link freezes up, that sort of cold will have such deleterious effects on suspension movement (feels like the compression and rebound settings are dialed way in) and braking (if they're hydraulic) that one realizes the bike shouldn't be ridden. All that takes place about the time the cold fingers and feet become nearly unbearable.